# nvidia-docker with nvidia-cuda-toolkit not working between different hosts

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I have two machines with different OS. One is ubuntu 18.04 and the other is debian buster. Both of them have docker installations ( [from here](http://get.docker.com) ) and and the latest nvidia-docker installed. Both systems have a gpu which I want to use inside the containers. So I created a dockerfile which will install everything I require.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install \
    nvidia-cuda-toolkit \
    -y
```

In the first machine which has as host ubuntu and a gpu that require .435 driver to work it works fine (`docker run --rm --gpus all my-image:1 nvidia-smi`)

But when I try the same dockerfile with 0 changes on my Debian machine it will return missmatched version of drivers.
The second matching which has as a host debian and a gpu that require .418 dirver to work it complains about missmatched versions.

Isn't supposed to be host independent installation ? What am I missing and I cannot build the same Dockerfile in both systems?

I can see toolkit bringing drivers on its own but as it is apt installation I have no control over it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm seeing here https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/tree/master/docker/amd64 that there are two different Dockerfiles for ubuntu and debian. The debian one has a FROM debian:${VERSION_ID} directive, instead of from ubuntu. Have you tried this?

Comment: nvidia-docker was installed from this repository. I haven't tried changing the directive as I was expecting the same Dockerfile ( as its not related to nvidia... Its supposed to be managed by the native installation ). :/